# Time series linear regression vs Linear regression

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-regression

Is it okay if my outcome for time series linear regression and linear regression is the same?

I have time series data with 756 observations and for each year there are 252 observations. The time series data is from 2015-2021. It is an individual data type.

All my independent variables are categorical and I categorized them.

I created a time series linear regression model and a linear regression model. My goal is to find the best model that fits the time series data from the two models.

[image: multiple linear regression model]
[image: Time series linear regression model]

The outputs are the same. Isn't it supposed to be different?

Comment: You should be much more specific about what kind of time series linear regression. Can you describe more precisely the models you fitted?

Comment: `tslm` only differs from `lm` when you have a trend or season variabel. See the documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.21/topics/tslm

Answer (score 8):

As said in the comment, "time-series linear regression" is not a different model. As [its documentation says](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.21/topics/tslm)

> `tslm` is largely a wrapper for `lm()` except that it allows variables "trend" and "season" which are created on the fly from the time series characteristics of the data. The variable "trend" is a simple time trend and "season" is a factor indicating the season (e.g., the month or the quarter depending on the frequency of the data).

If you didn't use those extra terms, the two models are exactly the same, not only mathematically, but it is also exactly the same code underneath.

Comment: So, meaning if I add trend as the independent variable, the output will be different, is it? Is it okay to add trend as one of the variables in the time series linear regression model?

Comment: @PriscillaRaj I don;t understand your question. The point of `tslm` is to easily be able to add trend and seasonality as variables to the model without creating them manually.

Comment: tslm(Life_expectancy~Age+Gender+Race+trend, data=ts_df). Can I do something like this? I actually tried using this as a model and I got a different outcome but the p-value of trend variable was insignificant. Does that mean that there is no trend in my data?

Comment: @PriscillaRaj if you have more questions on using `tslm`, ask them as new questions.